# What are the /firmware and /efs partitions on Samsung devices

Tags: partitions

This is specifically the Galaxy s3.  Out of curiosity what are these partitions exactly.  Are they part of the android OS or something lower level than that? If I were to delete everything in these partitions will I brick the phone even after a complete factory restore from "Download mode"? If these are not in fact android partitions why do some ROMs flash them?  What is the difference between `/firmware` and `/efs` and are these flashed with most ROMS?

I've been googling the partition structure of my device and these things are not clear. Please help me clear them up :)

Answer (score 3):

According to this [linky](http://www.jayceooi.com/2011/11/19/how-to-backup-restore-samsung-galaxy-s2-efs/) here this is what it has to say

> What is EFS? It is a place that stores your Android smartphone
>   important data like Wi-Fi, Bluetooth MAC address and IMEI
>   (nv_data.bin).

After reading the above linky, it would be prudent to make a backup of that partition otherwise well and truly hosed! :)

As for `/firmware` I am guessing that is where the original stock firmware goes into when updating via the official route a lá Kies.

If anyone has a better insight feel free to comment, and I will gladly amend this accordingly :)

Comment: I read that link before posting here.  I do not have an IMEI as I use a CDMA phone.  There are a lot of "nv items" I can edit through a tool called QXDM however I'm not sure if they are reading from the same EFS partition.  Is this partition completely separate of the Android OS and actually a separate NVRAM chip that holds radio information?

Comment: There's some partitions that are "best left alone" even though I can understand your curiousity! :) That partition - actually do this - enter this from `adb shell`, enter `mount`, does it show up in the list, if not, they are "hidden" from Android OS itself. :) TIL - CDMA does not have an IMEI... never knew that! Hah! Learnt something there! :)

Comment: CDMA phones use [ESNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_serial_number) instead. The concept is pretty much equivalent, though, so I wouldn't be surprised if the `/efs` partition will have your ESN on a CDMA device.

Answer (score 1):

## /firmware

Modem's firmware mount point .Store the firmware of the modem same as the  `modem.bin` in the odin tar.md5 flasheable firmware. I see it in Fat16

## /efs

Stores the wifi and Bluetooth  mac adress, some network data , IMEI data (In some samsung phones, not in all models).