# What considerations govern working with the /firmware partition?

Tags: device-firmware

In some recovery options (such as ClockworkMod recovery's advanced options on some devices), there is a `Format /firmware` option.  I have searched for descriptions of this partition, but have found little:

- [This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27341) asks about it, but there is no authoritative
  answer.
- Stock ROMs that I have do not modify this partition.
- I see it mounted on some devices as:

  ```
  /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/modem /firmware ext4 ro,context=u:object_r:firmware_file:s0,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
  ```

What are the logistical considerations surrounding this partition, including:

1. What does the `/firmware` partition usually contain?
2. Is it on all Android devices or just a subset?
3. What are the consequences of formatting it?
4. Can its contents be recreated?

etc.

Comment: For future necromancers: I'm still interested in finding an answer to this one! :)